# MS Sync Framework: synchronize 1 client DB with 2 server databases

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework, .net-cf-3.5

Working on occasionally connected application on Windows Mobile devices. Application stores data locally in SQL CE database which is synced with MSSQL DB using MS Sync Framework (via web service).

Now it's necessary to sync mobile DB with 2 different server databases.
I.e. SQL CE database has tables A,B,C. Tables A and B should be synced with tables A and B on ServerDatabase1, and table C should be synced with table C on ServerDatabase2.

I'm thinking of creating a second set of Sync objects (SyncAgent and SyncProvider) that will be used for syncing with second database. But I was wondering if there's some other more convenient way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

that should work for as long as you're always synching the same table to the same server. i.e., table C always synched table C in ServerDatabase2.

the sync provider you're using has a table that contains "anchors" for every table you sync. The anchors are for last sent and last received timestamps (if you're using timestamps). There's only one row for each table, so it cannot keep track of the sync status of each table against multiple sync partners.

a received anchor from Server A will be different from the anchors in Server B. so it will break if you sync the same table with Server A and then sync with Server B

Comment: That's not the case- each table in compact Db is going to be synced with only one of server Dbs, and always the same one.